Get the bounds of overflowing objects to shrink to parent view
I'm making a representation of the unit circle and I have the point labels arranged in a circle.  I know the origin of the labels are at the center, so they overflow the parent.
Whats the best way to remedy this?  Is there a way to grab the bounds of the overflow and just resize them to fit inside  the group, or a different solution?
struct UnitCircle: View {
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      let diameter = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
      let radius = (diameter / 2)
      
      Group {
        ForEach(unitCirclePoints, id: \.angle) { point in
          VStack {
            PointView(point: point).border(.red).scaleEffect(0.3)
          }
          .position(
            x: radius * CGFloat(cos(Double(-point.angle) * .pi / 180)) + radius,
            y: radius * CGFloat(sin(Double(-point.angle) * .pi / 180)) + radius
          )
        }
      }.border(.red)
      
        .frame(width: diameter, height: diameter)
        .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2)
    }
  }
}



Just make the radius smaller.
For example, here I have reduced the radius by 30pt.
let diameter = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
let radius = (diameter / 2) - 30 // here

Group {
    ForEach(stride(from: 0, to: 360, by: 45).map { Double($0) }, id: \.self) { point in
        // as an example, I will be drawing 8 smaller circles, instead of the coordinates
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 30)
            .position(
                // here you need to add back the 30pt so that the circle is centered
                x: radius * cos(-point * .pi / 180) + radius + 30,
                y: radius * sin(-point * .pi / 180) + radius + 30
            )
    }
}
.border(.red)
.frame(width: diameter, height: diameter)
.position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2)

Alternatively, try drawing these on a Canvas. You have a lot more control over drawing there. Specifically, you can get the size of the view that you are drawing. You can use this to determine how much the view exceeds the bounds, and move the view accordingly.
Here is an example where I draw the angle in degrees around a circle. If the text would normally have intersected the canvas, I would move it so that it is just inside the canvas. This does not consider the texts intersecting each other.
let angles = stride(from: 0, to: 360, by: 45).map { Double($0) }
Canvas { gc, size in
    let radius = size.width / 2
    let canvasBounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    for angle in angles {
        guard let symbol = gc.resolveSymbol(id: angle) else { continue }
        let x = radius * cos(-angle * .pi / 180) + radius
        let y = radius * sin(-angle * .pi / 180) + radius
        let proposedFrame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 0, height: 0)
            .insetBy(dx: -symbol.size.width / 2, dy: -symbol.size.height / 2)
        if canvasBounds.contains(proposedFrame) {
            // the view does not intersect the canvas
            gc.draw(symbol, at: .init(x: x, y: y), anchor: .center)
        } else {
            let dx: CGFloat
            if proposedFrame.minX < canvasBounds.minX {
                // the view intersects the left edge of the canvas
                dx = canvasBounds.minX - proposedFrame.minX
            } else if proposedFrame.maxX > canvasBounds.maxX {
                // the view intersects the right edge of the canvas
                dx = canvasBounds.maxX - proposedFrame.maxX
            } else {
                dx = 0
            }
            let dy: CGFloat
            if proposedFrame.minY < canvasBounds.minY {
                // the view intersects the top edge of the canvas
                dy = canvasBounds.minY - proposedFrame.minY
            } else if proposedFrame.maxY > canvasBounds.maxY {
                // the view intersects the bottom edge of the canvas
                dy = canvasBounds.maxY - proposedFrame.maxY
            } else {
                dy = 0
            }
            gc.draw(symbol, at: .init(x: x + dx, y: y + dy), anchor: .center)
        }
        
    }
} symbols: {
    ForEach(angles, id: \.self) { angle in
        Text("\(angle)")
            .border(.orange)
            .tag(angle)
    }
}
.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
.border(.red)

Output:


Sweet!  I like the second option, i didn't want mess around guessing the radius.  The second option works great and has the added bonus of being able to scale my labels nicely!

@Ashbury I just noticed that you use scaleEffect. This will not change symbol.size, so you need to multiply the size manually.

I did!  And noticed that the symbols still have SVG crispness, whereas before it was like resizing a raster image.
